# what is the real advantage of encapsulation, and why is it specific to OOP

Tags: oop, encapsulation

I'm reading lots of definitions about encapsulation, such as:

> Encapsulation is the process of binding data and code together to make a single unit.

or

> It describes the idea of bundling data and methods that work on that data within one unit.

1-so why combining data and code in the same unit is OOP specific? I imagine we can achieve this even in non OOP programming languages like C, we could separate our code and data into multiple file(s).c and we have our code and data separated according to desired semantics, is there a difference between separating (according to semantics) a program in C into multi-files or a program in java into multi-classes?

2-What is the real benefit of encapsulation, I'm looking for a real example that compares a program written in non OOP (C) and another in an OOP language (java).

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, out of the four principles of OO namely *Information hiding*, *abstractions*, *encapsulation* and *inheritance*, I feel only *Inheritance* is a true OO feature which can not be easily simulated in Procedural programming. As you have mentioned, other three can be implemented by appropriate partitioning of the code.

Only I feel in Object oriented languages like Java, its easier for programmer to achieve these principles by simply implementing class and put required constraints on the access. In procedural programming (e.g. C) programmer has to take efforts and follow discipline in programming. Mastering this technique of writing such C program remains special skill, where as implementing OO java code becomes matter of following specific rules. Finally it will impact productivity with available skill set in the market.

Answer (score 0):

I started writing this as a comment and realized that I was running up against the character limit. So I have to turn my comment into some sort of *quasi-answer*:

Yours is an excellent question and many many books have been written to answer it. The short answer is that if you have a *small* programming problem, it probably does not matter too much how you go about approaching a solution. But often problems are big. *Programming in the large* is best approached by decomposing these large problems into smaller problems or pieces. The C language, which lends itself to top-down structure programming, suggests a decomposition along the *verbs* of the problem domain, that is to say, what is being done. In contrast, object-oriented programming decomposes a problem by identifying the *nouns* or *objects* within the problem domain. These objects, of course, also exhibit behavior. It is hoped that these objects become reusable in other problems that will arise within the same domain.

There is a second kind of algorithmic reusability that arises from object-oriented programming. Let's consider the simple case of a bank with many kinds of banking accounts in which interest is computed in many different ways according to the account type. But regardless of the account type, it is clear that each month an account balance increases by the interest that has been earned by the account for the month. So you can imagine that every month the following takes place:

```
For each account:
   balance = account.getCurrentBalance()
   interest = account.computeMonthlyInterest()
   newBalance = balance + interest
   account.setBalance(newBalance)
```

Because of *polymorphism* along with encapsulation, method `computeMonthlyInterest` will compute the interest in a way this is appropriate to the type of account on which the method is being called. The point is that the above (very simple) algorithm becomes applicable and reusable for all account types and can be placed within a *controller* object because each account type knows how to compute its own interest and thus the algorithm does not have to be duplicated in each account type.